# Get custom field value with ruby in Redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine

I'm writing plugin for redmine that will notify users with SMS about an issue, so I've created a custom field "Phone Number" and now I want to get its value in ruby. I get subject of an issue like this:

```
subject = @issue.id
```

How can I get user's custom field value if I only have an issue? I know about issue's "assigned_to_id" but I cannot realise how to use it.
Help me please.

Comment: @Yergor can you show your user and your issue model.

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza, it's Yegor, actually. I've already solved the problem by following code:  
    **my_user = User.find(@issue.assigned_to_id)  
    phone_number = my_user.custom_value_for(1)** sorry, don't know how to linebreak